# jQuery.post() is sending a GET request?

Tags: jquery, get, jsonp, put

I wasn't getting the responses I was supposed to when using jQuery.post(), so I looked at my server logs and I'm actually receiving a GET request. What am I missing? Is it because I'm using `jsonp` as my datatype? Here's my jquery:

```
$.post('xxx', 'server=xxx', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $.post('xxx', 'username=xxx&password=xxx', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.get('xxx', function (data) {
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(data);
        }, "jsonp");
    } , "jsonp")
}, "jsonp");
```

And my server logs clearly showing I'm sending GET requests.

```
[11/Oct/2014 21:01:48] "GET ...
[11/Oct/2014 21:01:48] "GET ...
[11/Oct/2014 21:01:48] "GET ...
```

Comment: JSONP cannot use POSTs.

Answer (score 2):

`jsonp` is, by definition, implemented by inserting a script tag which requests a script (which is allowed cross-domain).  When the browser processes that script tag, it turns it into a GET request for that script.  You can't do a POST with a jsonp call.

You should only be using jsonp for cross domain calls where you generally wouldn't be allowed to do a POST anyway.  JSONP is a work-around for cross domain access, but as such, can only do a GET for a script file.